# ant script to use use two .properties files?

Tags: ant, properties-file

I want to know if it is possible to get an ant script to reference 2 different `.properties` files at once, and if so, how to accomplish this.

Assume that the properties contained within the two `.properties` files are mutually exclusive, i.e. the same property will not appear twice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220381/ash) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912422/ant-script-to-use-use-two-properties-files/1912496#1912496).

You can use a different `prefix` attribute of `property` task, e.g

```
<property file="file1.properties" prefix="file1"/>
<property file="file2.properties" prefix="file2"/>
```

This way you can find out if both files have same properties and differentiate between them in your build script.  For example if both files have property `test`, then after they are loaded with the above commands you will end up with properties named `file1.test` and `file2.test`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - can't believe I overlooked that!

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to import any number of properties files with multiple `<property file="...">` entries in your ant script (unless there's some subtlety to your question that I've missed?). Duplicate properties are OK, since in ant properties are immutable and whoever sets the property first "wins".

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately I can only check one answer.